# Xcode updated to 7.2 but still shows 7.1 only

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I recently updated my xcode to 7.2 from Mac App store. But all i see a new Xcode 7.1 and so cannot run the app on my iOS 9.2 iPhone 5s. Moreover, the starnge thing is, Mac App store shows that Xcode 7.2 is downloaded and insalled and also shows that Xcode 7.2 is remaining to be downloaded. How come? Can anyone help me solve this issue

Thanks,
Anil[image]

Comment: try restarting system

Comment: already restarted as i had updated security settings as well. So it restart my system already.

Comment: u can also try uninstal xcode and reinstalling

Comment: That means i have download again from app store right? I can't do that as we have low speed internet and it would take many hours for this to finish download and install

Comment: Your update might be interrupted . You have to reinstall xcode (download xocde and install). No magic will happen itself .

Comment: You can use 7.2 disk image to run in your iOS 9.2 iPhone 5s as an temporary alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by downloading [XCode 7.2 dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and installed it as a new copy.

or

Uninstall exiting one and directly download new version of xcode from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to delete the app and reinstall the app from AppStore. But, as I have a very low speed of internet to download the new Xcode from app store will take too much time and in that case I will not be able to work until download will finished. So, I left with an option to download xcode DMG file from the developer site.

But I found the solution that satisfied my both needs.
1) Keeping the old version of xcode. So, I can work until it gets downloaded
2) Download the latest xcode from AppStore and not from developer site (DMG file).

**Steps:-**

1. Rename the existing xcode by appending its version number. In my case, I changed Xcode.app to Xcode_7_1.app
2. Delete the xcode app that you have renamed on step-1. (Make sure the deleted copy of Xcode has to be in Trash)
3. Download the latest app from Xcode as It will so "Install/Download/Get" option instead of "Open"
4. Once downloading will start, go to your Trash folder and use "Put Back" by selection option from menu why you double tap on Xcode application.