# Not able to open xcode 7.2 after updating

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am not able to open xcode 7.2.The current version of my running xcode is showing xcode 7.1.1 though I have updated my xcode to 7.2 the day before.I am not able to run my code on my ipad running ios 9.2.It is showing “**could not find developer disk image**” .In appstore my current xcode version is showing xcode 7.2 and I can’t see any update link.

In the list of recently installed softwares I can see xcode 7.2. BUt when I open xcode ,the version that opens up is xcode 7.1.1

These are the reviews from appstore.

[image]

How can I run my code in my ipad(ios 9.2) now?

This is my os version. os x 10.11.2 EL capitan.

Comment: Have you checked mac OS version i.e., 10.11.2. Then only you will get Xcode 7.2.

Comment: my os version is 10.11.2.

Comment: I need a solution,Not downvotes..pls

Comment: i didn't down vote .I have resolved by updating mac OS.

Comment: Do you think reinstalling xcode will solve the issue?

Comment: Yes go to App Store check for updates and install Xcode again.

Comment: Why people click not useful? I had the same issue! OS 10.10.5.

Comment: Don't know why people do that.I spent hours trying to figure out this issue.

Comment: I don't know why some people downvote such a relevant question. Many of us struggled with the same and spent a lot of hours in vain which, we could have better utilized. If community guideline restricts someone asking such a valid question, we should change the guideline not the question. Upvoted as such.

Comment: Check out following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34978434/1748956

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same issue. I fixed it by downloading XCode 7.2 dmg and installed it as a new copy.

Comment: let me try.Thanks for the response

Comment: Where did you download the dmg?  When I go to developer.apple.com, the only download link points to the Mac App Store...

Comment: @Nerrolken i posted a seprate ans for you

Comment: @Nerrolken it's dumb isn't it ? They don't give you a link on their website to the direct download page and just tells everyone to go to download from Mac AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are interested to download the Xcode dmg or any dmg file of available developer resources please follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)

Just click on dmg and it will start downloading.[image]

Comment: @nerrolken here is the link and way to download the dmg

Comment: Thanks for the link! May be it would come up handy :)